# Homotopy sequence of a weak fibration with a section

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, exact-sequence, higher-homotopy-groups

Suppose that $p:E \to B$ is a weak fibration with a section $s:B \to E$ ($p \circ s=id_B$). Also here $F=p^{-1}(b_0)$.

I need to show that the sequence $0 \to \pi_n(F,s(b_0)) \xrightarrow {i_*}\pi_n(E,s(b_0)) \xrightarrow {p_*} \pi_n(B,b_0) \to 0$ is exact for every $n \geq1$.

Only thing that I don't seem to get is the exactness at $\pi_n(F,s(b_0))$. From other posts I have read that this follows from the boundary map being identically zero, since $p_*$ is surjective/onto but this is not explained any [further](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2352190/on-long-exact-sequence-of-homotopy-groups-and-splitting). Could someone enlighten me how this follows?

Comment: Isn't it more common to mean just a Serre fibration with ''weak fibration'', and not a fiber bundle?

Comment: Ah, yes my bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $p_*$ is surjective (which follows from the existence of section) then the boundary map $\partial:\pi_n(B)\to\pi_{n-1}(F)$ in the long exact sequence of homotopy groups has to be the zero map (because its kernel is the image of $p_*$). And this means that $i_*$ is injective, because its kernel is the image of $\partial$ which is trivial. So I can cut the long exact sequence and simply add $0$ before $i_*$, since we already know that it is injective.

Comment: Thank you so much! Now I feel blind for not noticing this :D...